# Convergence of moments implies convergence in total variation for Normal distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, solution-verification, weak-convergence

I would appreciate some proof verification on the following statement concerning convergence in total variation for Normal Distributions, given convergence of the first and second moments.

I suppose it is true, but a quick google search and search on this site did not bring it up, so this made me doubt.

**Question:**

We are dealing with the total variation norm, defined as $$||P-Q||_{TV} = \underset{B}{\sup} |P(B) - Q(B)|.$$

Suppose we have sequences of random variables $\mu_n$,$\sigma_n^2$, such that 
$$\mu_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} M$$

and
$$\sigma_n^2 \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} c ,$$

where $c$ is some constant and $M$ is a random variable. We want to show that $$||\mathcal{N}(\mu_n,\sigma_n^2) - \mathcal{N}(M,c)||_{TV} \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0$$

**Proof:**

We can use [Pinsker's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality), which states that
$$ ||P-Q||_{TV} \leq \sqrt{D_{KL}(P||Q)}.$$

The Kullback-Leibler Divergence for the two normal distributions in question is given by

$$ \frac{1}{2} ( \frac{\sigma_n^2}{c} - 1 + \frac{(\mu_n - M)^2}{c} + \ln (\frac{c}{\sigma_n^2}) ,$$

which converges in probability to $0$ by our assumptions (using Slutsky's Lemma, continuos mapping theorem and the fact that weak convergence to a constant implies convergence in probability to a constant). Thus the proof is complete

**Additional question**:
Could one also replace the convergence of the variances by convergence to some random variable? We could then not use Slutsky's theorem any more to get the convergence to $0$ of the last expression.

Comment: $\sigma_n^2$ is a positive number and not a random variable! We are talking on the convergence of a sequence of real numbers.  The convergence in term of total variation result from Sheffé's lemma easily, since the convergence in distribution of a sequence of normal distribution is also a normal distribution, which means that $\sigma^2_n$ and $\mu_n$ converges, and then the density $f_n$ converges pointwise to a normal density $f,$ and now apply Sheffé's lemma!

Comment: Thank you, but I am indeed talking about both $\mu_n$ and $\sigma^2_n$ being random variables.

Comment: If you want to use Slutsky lemma in $ \frac{1}{2} ( \frac{\sigma_n^2}{c} - 1 + \frac{(\mu_n - M)^2}{c} + \ln (\frac{c}{\sigma_n^2}),$ you should have $(\mu_n,M,\sigma_n^2)$ converges in distribution to $(M,M,c)$, which means that $\mu_n$ converges in probability to $M,$ (If $X_n$ converges in distribution to X, this doesn't mean that $X_n-X$ converges in distribution to $0$)

Comment: Oh yes you are right, so the proof does not work... Do you think there is a fix for that, or would you think the assumption is wrong as stated?

Comment: If we have convergence in probability $\mu_n$ to $M$, it will work, in term of convergence in distribution, in general this is false, unless if you have other information on $M,$ for example supposing that $M$ is constant a.s. Out of curiosity, can I ask from where is this question? (In your question the random variable are definied as an integral under Lebesgue measure)

Comment: I did not take this question from a book or something, I came up with it when studying van der Vaart's book on asymptotic statistics, and therin the section on the Bernstein-von-Mises theorem; where one has that the (rescaled) posterior converges in total variation to some Normal, with the mean being a random variable and the variance being a constant. I thus wondered what happens if I take the corresponding rescaled versions of some point estimators (eg. MLE), $\mu_n = \sqrt{n} (\hat{\mu}_n - \mu_0)$ and $\sigma_n^2= n \hat{\sigma}_n^2$ and look at the limit of a normal density based on these